# PHP Display HTML between certain dates

Tags: php, html

I have 3 different banners I'd like to display at certain dates.

```
<div>
   <?php if(somedate1 === today) { ?>
       <div class="banner-1"></div>
   <?php } else if(somedate2 === today) { ?>
       <div class="banner-2"></div>
   <?php } else if(somedate3 === today) { ?>
       <div class="banner-3"></div>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
```

In my research, I have found many different ways to accomplish this. I am wondering what is the most efficient and modern way to select and compare dates in PHP?

Comment: what do the dates you're comparing look like?

Comment: Are you using some php framework or managing it with MVC by yourself. Or neither of them ?

Comment: you are missing the closing `}` before you `else if`-s

Comment: Why are you comparing the same `somedate` each time?

Comment: That's just psudo code. @Barmar

Comment: It's bad pseudo code. At least give them different names, like `else if (sometherdate == today)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you will have to check whether the date is before, or is after today's date, whatever you need.

To do so you can use [PHP's `strtotime()` function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp)

```
<?php
    if(strtotime('12-01-2015') > strtotime('today')) {
        //Given date is after today
    } else {
        //Given date is before today
    }
?>
```

In the `if()` the code checks if the given date, in this case 12-01-2015, is after today's date, if it's not, it will execute the code given in the `else`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect!

Comment: Not a problem, please do not forget to mark this as the correct answer so people with the same problem can quickly find the right answer.